# can await/async makes blocking to non-blocking process in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I read this article from node

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

It says the code below is a process blocker:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('/file.md'); // blocks here until file is read
console.log(data);
// moreWork(); will run after console.log
```

what if I add await?
will the code above becomes non-blocking or it will stay in its true nature?

Example code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = await fs.readFileSync('/file.md'); // no more blocking
console.log(data);
```

Thank you

Comment: No. `fs.readFileSync` is always blocking. Putting an `await` in front of it does not help. You have to actually use `fs.readFile` (without `…Sync`) to get the non-blocking behaviour. Then you can use promises to simplify dealing with asynchronous results, and `async`/`await` as syntactic sugar for `then` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code can't run since await must use in [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).

And await should use for function that return promise.

the code means:

```
// await new Promise(...)
// console.log(...)

new Promise().then((...) => console.log(...))
```

If you should non-block function, you should use `fs.readFile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Blocking means that the whole application is blocked.

So, all `SetInterval`, `Promise`, `Events` or whatever `async callback` are paused until that sync function ends its execution.

It's the same of what you get when you use a `for..loop`.

NodeJS provides you some non-blocking `file system` methods with callbacks, just change your code like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/file.md', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data)
});
```

There is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

**await operator wait a promise, and wrapped in async function**

you should code like this

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function readFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

async function f1() {
  try {
    var x = await readFile("foo.json");
    console.log(x);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // 30
  }
}

f1();
```